# Accessing value of DependencyProperty in Setter.Value Tag

Tags: wpf, styles, dependency-properties, setter

I have a Control that changes it's color whe the Mouse gets over it. I tried to solve it by using a Style for the Control:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Control}">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="MouseHoverBackgroundColor" Value="#FFFFEFBB" />
    <Setter Property="MouseHoverBorderColor" Value="#FFE5C365" />
    <Setter Property="MouseHoverBorderThickness" Value="2" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">

            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <!-- Here I have to get the Value of the current "MouseHoverBackgroundColor"-DependencyProperty. -->
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <!-- MouseHoverBorderColor -->
        </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>   
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness">
                <Setter.Value>
            <!-- MouseHoverBorderColor -->
            </Setter.Value>
            </Setter> 

        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I actually don't know how to access the current Value of the DependencyProperty.

Sincerely

user1574054

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you don't want to set `MouseHoverBorderColor` for `BorderThickness` like your question asks for and instead use `MouseHoverBorderThickness`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Control}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="MouseHoverBackgroundColor" Value="#FFFFEFBB" />
    <Setter Property="MouseHoverBorderColor" Value="#FFE5C365" />
    <Setter Property="MouseHoverBorderThickness" Value="2" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">    
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=MouseHoverBackgroundColor}">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=MouseHoverBorderColor}">
            </Setter>   
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=MouseHoverBorderThickness}">
            </Setter>    
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I do hope there is another reason for you using this approach though of having a separate DP for Hover Color and sorts.

If all you wanted was to change color on a trigger just create brushes as style resources and apply corresponding brushes when trigger is invoked. Saves you having to create dependency properties for such stuff

Say with something like (You can change the ControlTemplate to what you want ofc):

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle"
        TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Style.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.IsMouseOver.Background"
                      Color="#FFFFEFBB" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.IsMouseOver.BorderColor"
                      Color="#FFE5C365" />
    <Thickness x:Key="Button.IsMouseOver.Thickness">2</Thickness>
  </Style.Resources>
  <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="Transparent" />
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
          Value="{x:Null}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
          Value="0" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
          <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
              Value="true">
      <Setter Property="Background"
              Value="{StaticResource Button.IsMouseOver.Background}" />
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
              Value="{StaticResource Button.IsMouseOver.BorderColor}" />
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
              Value="{StaticResource Button.IsMouseOver.Thickness}" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```